# I sent ETH to an Opensea Ownable Delegate Proxy Contract, Is there anyway to retrieve it?

Tags: opensea, proxy-contracts

I accidentally sent ETH funds to the Ownable Delegate Proxy contract owned by my address. However, i am not a developer and have no know-how as to how i could obtain these funds back or if that is even possible…

I tried contacting Opensea and looking up online but i cannot find the answer. Maybe someone in this community has the answer?

Here is the address: 0x1F27a35e269146105732F7037F2EC9B5846C632A

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can upgrade the contract to give it the ETH back. For example to this implementation:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

contract Retriever {
    address constant owner = 0xcE3A78F8e46A4239DaD4AFc42B29d2DB7a66A450;

    constructor() {}

    fallback() external {
        (bool success, ) = owner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        require(success);
    }
}
```

I know this might be a little difficult if you have no dev experience, but try following this steps:

1. Go to https://remix.ethereum.org.
2. Click on the blue button "Start Coding", it should open a file.
3. Replace the contents of the file with the code I wrote above. Ignore the warnings.
4. On the bar on the left, there's a "Solidity compiler" tab. Go there and click the blue button "Compile HelloWorld.sol".
5. Same bar on the left, go to "Deploy & run transactions".
6. There's an "ENVIRONMENT" window on top, choose the Injected Provider to connect to metamask. Be sure to be on ethereum chain.
7. Click on the orange button "Deploy".

If you ended making a successful transaction, it means the contract got deployed.

8. Go to https://etherscan.io/address/0x1f27a35e269146105732f7037f2ec9b5846c632a/advanced#writeContract
9. On the "write contract" tab, there's "Connect to Web3" button. Connect your metamask, using the account that owns the contract.
10. Click on "upgradeToAndCall" and fill the fields as follows:

- payableAmount -> `0`
- implementation ->  write the address of the contract you deployed earlier
- data -> leave it empty or `0x00` (it doesn't matter)

11. Click on "Write" button.

The transaction should be successful, and you should see the ETH in your account. If you get stuck somewhere, let me know in a comment.